Match content from Nth Occurrence of + to Nth Occurrence of '
Team,
I wants to Extract the content between 2nd occurance of + to first occurrence of ' from the line which starts with TXF+3.
ERC+21236:EC'
TXF+3:::::M:2+THERE IS NO ITEM IN THE PRINTER DELIVERY'+Printer jammed'+'No Paper'
UNT+5+1'

The below expression giving me result until end of the line, I want this to be stopped after first occurrence of ', please do help.
My attempt:
TXF\+3:::::M:\w+\+(?<Y>.*)'

Expected Result:
THERE IS NO ITEM IN THE PRINTER DELIVERY

Actual Result:
THERE IS NO ITEM IN THE PRINTER DELIVERY**'+Printer jammed'+'No Paper' UNT+5+1


Use a reluctant quantifier *? instead of the greedy quantifier *: TXF\+3:::::M:\w+\+(?<Y>.*?)'
